# How to use custom type function pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

**Condition**

I use a framework that has an custom type as bellow:

```
typedef log (*CustomType) (
  int timeStamp,
  const char* data,
  int dataSize,
  void* userData,
  int dataType,
  int viewId
)
```

and MyClass init method as bellow:

```
MyClass_Init (void **output, CustomType video, CustomType audio, void* userData)
```

**Question**

I used init method like bellow but always receive error (error content is not displayed because i use a framework). pls point me what is missed.

```
CustomType videoInput;
CustomType audioInput;
void *output  = malloc(sizeof(void*);
void *userData = malloc(sizeof(void*));                     
long result = MyClass_Init(&output, videoInput, audioInput, userData);
```

Comment: What is your error output?

Answer (score 1):

A number of things wrong with this code:

1. You can't intermix function pointers and method pointers. What it boils down to is that the `this` for a method has to be included in the method call signature. Since the function pointer doesn't include the `this` pointer (it is a function, not a method pointer), the two can not match.

   Most C-based API includes some sort of reference value (most frameworks call those refCon, context or userData), so what you can do is create an adapter function that calls your method. The `userData` parameter in your CustomType parameter list looks like it is one of those (consult the docs to be sure).

   You can probably provide a userData wherever you set MyClass_Init as your callback now. So, if that function to provide a callback to the library was called `set_callback( MyCustomType callback, void* userData )`, do something like

   ```
     MyClass *obj = new MyClass; // Or however you create your object
     set_callback( MyClassCallbackAdapterFunction, obj );
   ```

   with an adapter function like:

   ```
     log MyClassCallbackAdapterFunction( int timeStamp, const char* data, int dataSize, void* userData, int dataType, int viewId )
     {
         MyClass *myThis = (MyClass*) userData;

         // Here you can now call myThis->MyClass_Init( ... ) however you want to.
     }
   ```
2. The `malloc( sizeof(void*) )` statements look like you're misunderstanding return parameters (also called "side effects" by some teachers). I don't have the docs to whatever API/library you're using, but I'm pretty certain you're supposed to not just pass in buffers the size of a pointer. Either you'd just provide a pointer on the stack in which a buffer will be returned, or you provide a whole buffer (e.g. an array) and its size, and that is where the callback will write to or so.